# agent chat history problen in smack api

Tags: api, smack

i wrote a java program to connect with google talk using smack api
connection and sending receiving messages are working fine
then how can i get the chat history using smack api

there is one method AgentchatHistory in smack but how can i use it

Answer (score 1):

I believe AgentChatHistory is to support Openfire's feature call [fastpath](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1513). Don't think Google supports that. If you want chat history, you will have to implement it.